# If column B value exists in column C then change the font of the string in column B to Bold

Tags: excel, vba

Part 1: Check if column B values exist in column C. If yes then change the font of the string in column B to Bold.

Part 2: I've used the code below and it worked well. Never tried it with 50k rows.

```
Sub matching()

    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For x = 1 To LastRow

           'Column B = Username

            If Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Font.Bold = True Then Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value = "yay"

        Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you've already asked this, and then deleted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904076/if-b-value-exists-in-c-column-then-put-a-cell-yay

Comment: @Plato77 Hello, yes I've deleted because that was not accurate. This time I try to ask help for only the first part. Cheers.

Comment: You know that you do not need code for this? You can use Conditional formatting?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hey, I've already tried, but with Conditional formatting seems like the values aren't changing. Only appears to be changed. If it makes any sense.

Comment: **Please help me with Part 1! Would save me tons of time!** I was referring to `Part 1: Check if column B values exist in column C. If yes then change the font of the value in column B to Bold.`. This can be handled with conditional formatting

Comment: I think you may not be sure as to what exactly do you want. On one end you are asking about changing the font to bold on the other hand (in your title and code) you are trying to change the value if the font is bold????

Comment: @SiddharthRout My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to handle too many rows, is better to use `Dictionary` to store values of column C & use `Array` to store values in column B.

**Notes:**

- Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference (Tools - References - "Microsoft Scripting Runtime")
- Dictionary is case sensitive.
- You may need to change the sheet name in line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` to fulfill your needs

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub matching()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim LastRowB As Long, LastRowC As Long, Count As Long, x As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With ws

            'Find the lastrow of column B
            LastRowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            'Find the lastrow of column C
            LastRowC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

            'Set an array with the values in column B - We assume that values start from row 1
            arr = .Range("B1:B" & LastRowB)

            'Set the range of the dicitonary - We assume that values start from row 1
            Set rng = .Range("C1:C" & LastRowC)

            Count = 0
            'Loop range and create a dictionary with th eunique values
            For Each cell In rng

                If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                    dict.Add Key:=cell.Value, Item:=Count
                    Count = Count + 1
                End If

            Next cell

            'Loop the array & bold
            For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

                If dict.Exists(arr(x, 1)) Then
                    .Range("B" & x).Font.Bold = True
                End If

            Next x

        End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, when I'm trying to run your code it gives me a compile error: User-defined type not defined. At the Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary line.

Comment: you have to add some references. see `Notes` in the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Sub bold()
Dim lastrow As Double
Dim cel As Range
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cel In Range("B1" & ":B" & lastrow)
If Not ActiveSheet.Range("C:C").Find(cel.Value) Is Nothing Then cel.Font.bold = True
Next cel
End Sub
```